# onclick method not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to append a anchor tag when user select's an `option` from `select` and its appending the anchor tag properly when user select's any option from select.

code for appending anchor tag:

```
$(function () {
 //others codes ......
 $('#anchor_placeholder').append(
     "<a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' 
         onClick='placeholderclick("+$(option).val()+")'>" + $(option).val() + "</a>"
 );
});
function placeholderclick(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```

now when i click on a appended anchor link its does not show me any alert message, but if i remove the parameters of `placeholderclick("+$(option).val()+")` from the append function above then its showing me alert...

i am wondering how can i alert the parameter value (parameter values comes from append method)

please suggest or help me to solve this issue, sorry for my bad english,
thanks in advance.

Comment: placeholderclick(\""+$(option).val()+"\")'

Comment: $(option) is from bootstrap multiselect and everything working fine just a alert is not working..and if i remove the placeholderclick("+$(option).val()+") its strat showing alert

Comment: Unless values are only numbers, you must quote it when passing to `placeholderclick` e.g. `placeholderclick("some value")`, but because you are in a string already you'd need to use escaped quotes.

Comment: or `placeholderclick(\\'"+$(option).val()+"\\')'`

Comment: Also, it's not a good practice to append you anchor tag as string. Why don't you create an HTML element like `$('<a/>)` and then set it attributes.

Comment: @elcodedocle thanks a lot sir, really i was unaware to use excaped quotes, its working perfect now.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp thanks sir, but its just for styling purpose it will not have any internal or external link associated with it..and i will for sure do it by creating it using jquery as you have suggested.. thanks

Comment: + 1 to @MarcellFülöp's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape double quotes

```
    $('#anchor_placeholder').append(
        "<a class='btn btn-info btn-xs'onClick='placeholderclick(\""+$(option).val()+"\")'>" + $(option).val() + "</a>"
    );
```

Suppose you have selected value apple than your link generated will be like this

```
<a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' onClick='placeholderclick(apple)'>apple</a>
```

so javascript will see your value (apple) has variable which won't be present.

if you escape double quotes than your link will be like this

```
<a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' onClick='placeholderclick("apple")'>apple</a>
```

now your value (apple) will be consider as string.